# Sorting strings in MFC vs. C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, sorting, mfc

I have a legacy app that uses both C# and native C++ (MFC).  I need to sort strings on both sides so that they are in the same order.  The problem is that on the .NET side using `string.Compare` it comes out in a "culture-specific" way so that, for instance, "A_B" sorts before "A11" whereas in MFC, using `operator <`, "A11" sorts before "A_B".

I know I can change the .NET side to use Ordinal sorting, but that could break some foreign language sorting.  What I want is to change the MFC sorting so that it sorts in a "culture-specific" manner, like the .NET side.  I found `CompareStringEx` in the Win32 API, but am wondering if there is an MFC solution to this or something else I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obvious question: what are you using for C++ sorting? std::sort (or better std::stable_sort) also accepts a comparison function object. You may write your own using locale-aware _wcsicmp

Comment: I am using CString operator< (which uses `_mbscmp`)

Comment: Then don't use it and go with a locale-aware comparison function!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - that's what I am looking for - a comparison function that matches the .NET side.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC's CString class has [`Collate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314311.aspx) and `CollateNoCase` for locale-specific comparisons. I haven't tested them to assure they match .NETs collation order, but I'd *expect* that both use the same Win32 function(s), in which case they'd obviously match.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but Collate sorts in the same order as `<` with the examples I gave above.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: At a guess, you probably haven't told C++ about the locale you want to use. By default, it'll use the "C" locale, which basically isn't localized at all. My immediate reaction would be to try something like `setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "");` right after the program starts (or specify a locale name instead of just using the user's default locale as the empty string specifies).

Comment: Good answer - I was actually able to get it to work with something similar and a bit less intrusive to the whole program by using `_stricoll_l` and a locale created with `_create_locale(LC_COLLATE, "");` using the parameters you suggested.   Thanks!

Comment: `Collate` and `strcoll` are different than `CompareStringEx`. You need `CompareStringEx` for example to duplicate the sort order in Explorer. Also `CompareStringEx` is not available in ANSI.